# Python - Recursive function returns Runtime Error: Exception maximum recursion depth exceeded for bigger limits

Tags: python, mysql, recursion, recursive-query

I have a csv file which has 4 columns such as **NEW_ID, OLD_ID, CLOSE_DATE_TXT, NEW_DATE_TXT.**

The NEW_ID will have its corresponding OLD_ID.

The output should be, if the OLD_ID is same as NEW_ID then ignore that records. If the OLD_ID is not same as NEW_ID and also if the value is available as one of the values in NEW_ID then the OLD_ID, NEW_DATE_TXT, CLOSE_DATE_TXT needs to be list aggregated with "--".

The process needs to continue until the OLD_ID is not available as one of the values in NEW_ID till the end of the records.

In the attached example, you could see the the **NEW_ID with 29** is having **OLD_ID as 30**. And, the 30 is not available in the NEW_ID column and hence the process ends.

**Input**:
[Input Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbCOX.png)

**Output**:
[Output Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N22eN.png)

I tried self join using the SQL queries by uploading this data in Table but it doesn't work after 2 iterations.

Used merge option in Python but can't iterate for the **n** number of times.

Finally, created the below script that uses recursion which works for the minimum numbers(~1000) of records. What happens next is, it results in kernel restart while running in Spyder IDE. Also the script **Returns **Runtime Error: Exception maximum recursion depth exceeded**

So I tried splitting the source file, which is then worked till 3000 records.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Nov 15 16:13:56 2022

@author: SAPPES
"""

import csv
import pandas as pd
import sys
#sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)

filename ="INPUT_DATA.csv"
df_first = pd.read_csv('INPUT_DATA.csv',sep=",",dtype=str)
ids = {}
result = []
count = 0

#Converting the CSV data to the below dictionary format
with open(filename, 'r') as data:
    for line in csv.DictReader(data):
        var1={}
        var1[line['OLD_ID']]={'CLOSE_DATE_TXT':line['CLOSE_DATE_TXT'],'NEW_DATE_TXT':line['NEW_DATE_TXT']}
        ids[line['NEW_ID']]=var1

# Recursion function
def find_benf(key,interim,close_date,start_date):
  if ids.get(key):
    val = ids[key]
    val_key = list(val.keys())
    val_key = val_key[0]
    close_date.append(val[str(val_key)]['CLOSE_DATE_TXT'])
    start_date.append(val[str(val_key)]['NEW_DATE_TXT'])
    interim.append(val_key)
    return find_benf(val_key,interim,close_date,start_date)
  else:
    return interim,start_date,close_date



def listToString(s):
    str1 = "--"
    return (str1.join(s))

for index, row in df_first.iterrows():
#Checking the NEW_ID is matching with OLD_ID, if its not equal then proceed for the next steps
     if(row['NEW_ID']!=row['OLD_ID']):
        new_id = []
        close_date = []
        start_date = []
        id_list,start_date,close_date_list = find_benf(row[0],new_id,close_date,start_date)
        final_ID_list_2_str = listToString(id_list)
        final_start_date_list_2_str = listToString(start_date)
        final_close_date_list_list_2_str = listToString(close_date_list)
        s=[row[0],final_ID_list_2_str,final_start_date_list_2_str,final_close_date_list_list_2_str]
        result.append(s)
        df_second = pd.DataFrame(result)
        df_second.to_csv('OUT_FILE.csv',index=False,header=("NEW_ID","OLD_ID","CLOSE_DATE_TXT","NEW_DATE_TXT"),quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, encoding='utf-8')
ids.clear()
```

Could anyone please help me on altering the script that avoids the runtime error on recursion in Python.

Sample Data:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>NEW_ID</th><th>OLD_ID</th><th>CLOSE_DATE_TXT</th><th>NEW_DATE_TXT</th></tr><tr><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>06/25/2015</td><td>06/25/2015</td></tr><tr><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>11/17/2015</td><td>11/17/2015</td></tr><tr><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>09/30/2015</td><td>09/30/2015</td></tr><tr><td>25</td><td>26</td><td>02/21/2018</td><td>02/21/2018</td></tr><tr><td>26</td><td>27</td><td>02/21/2018</td><td>02/21/2018</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Output Required:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>NEW_ID</th><th>OLD_ID</th><th>CLOSE_DATE_TXT</th><th>NEW_DATE_TXT</th></tr><tr><td>10</td><td>11--12--13</td><td>06/25/2015--11/17/2015--09/30/2015</td><td>06/25/2015--11/17/2015--09/30/2015</td></tr><tr><td>11</td><td>12--13</td><td>11/17/2015--09/30/2015</td><td>11/17/2015--09/30/2015</td></tr><tr><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>09/30/2015</td><td>09/30/2015</td></tr><tr><td>25</td><td>26--27</td><td>02/21/2018--02/21/2018</td><td>02/21/2018--02/21/2018</td></tr><tr><td>26</td><td>27</td><td>02/21/2018</td><td>02/21/2018</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Recursion Function:

```
def find_benf(key,interim,close_date,start_date):
  if ids.get(key):
    val = ids[key]
    val_key = list(val.keys())
    val_key = val_key[0]
    close_date.append(val[str(val_key)]['CLOSE_DATE_TXT'])
    start_date.append(val[str(val_key)]['NEW_DATE_TXT'])
    interim.append(val_key)
    return find_benf(val_key,interim,close_date,start_date)
  else:
    return interim,start_date,close_date

id_list,start_date,close_date_list = find_benf(row[0],new_id,close_date,start_date)
```

P.S: the solution can be in any other mediums such as **Python**/**SQL Query/ETL tools(Informatica)**

Comment: *Input Data .. Output Data* [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: If you're getting this error, there are 2 likely causes: The base case condition is wrong, or the recursive call doesn't get you closer to the base case.

Comment: Could you please give me a clear explanation on where did I made the flaw. Else could you please give me any suggestion on how to resolve this ? Or any other solution. Anything is appreciated. @Barmar

Comment: I can't actually tell what this is doing. Can you simplify it to a [mre]? We don't need all the file-reading stuff, just sample data and the recursive function.

Comment: @Akina As per the tips uploaded the data under the snippets.

Comment: Added sample data and also mentioned where the expected Recursion happens. Could you please guide me on how to handle recursion depth.@Barmar

Comment: Either explain how a database is used, or remove the `[mysql]` tag.